# ContainerView Tab Bar?

Tags: ios, ios7, autolayout, xcode5

I have a container view in my view controller, which internally hosts a navigation controller, and eventually nests a view controller. The outer view controller (blue) has a tab bar, but the container (red) should not. However, it appears the tab controller exists in the container view, but only at run time. The storyboard never shows it. See the attached screenshots, they'll likely make more sense. (Note, storyboard scrunched to make it visible in one screenshot).

[image: Storyboard]
[image: At Runtime]

As you can see, the nested container has a gray area at the bottom, which is a tab bar. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's a `UIToolbar`, not a tab bar, since it is visible in the `UINavigationController` in your storyboard. You have two options:

1. In your storyboard, look at the properties of your nested `UINavigationController`. Disable the show toolbar option.
2. In your nested view controller (I'll call it `MyRedViewController`), put `[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:NO];` in `viewWillAppear:`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the option isn't checked in the storyboard (which you can see from the storyboard picture). I also tried calling your suggested line, but that didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: The frame of the toolbar, however, does match the what I'm seeing -- it's at the right point on the screen. For whatever that's worth.

Comment: Ah, the screenshot is too small. I thought I saw a UIToolbar where it was just the white background.